# Change date format to 'DD-MON-YYYY' in OBIEE

Tags: variables, date, prompt, obiee

i have a variable prompt using a sql query. this quesry gives the previous month end date.

SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY,DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) * -1 , CURRENT_DATE) s_1 FROM "FDM DDR"

query displays output in format dd/mm/yyyy.

this date output is an input to a ddr query. The ddr query fails because oracle accepts date in the format 'dd-mon-yyyy'.

so could you please suggest how should i change above query so that it displays date in the format 'dd-mon-yyyy' instead of 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

thanks.

Comment: Please include the ddr query

Comment: it could be something like this select * from table_x where business_date='@p_bus_dt';   Here p_bus_dt will be promt variable name where value will be assigned

Comment: Why don't you use a database specific query. SO, if you have Oracle database, you can use `select to_char(sysdate, 'dd/Mon/yyyy') from dual` as you anyways would be storing it the variable p_bus_dt.